# Outputting Literal curly braces in Liquid templates

Tags: templates, liquid

I'm trying to output the following from within a liquid template:

```
{{ example }}
```

Obviously, Liquid sees this as a variable named `example` and tries to do substitution. I'm trying to find out how I can output the actual braces.

So far, I've found one method that works, but it's incredibly ugly:

```
{{ '{example'|prepend:'{' }}}}
```

Yeah, told you it was gross.

Here are other things I've tried:

```
{{{ example }}}     # outputs '}'
{{{{ example }}}}   # outputs '}}'
\{\{ example \}\}   # outputs '\{\{ example \}\}'
```

Any advice here?

Comment: Aside from the 'raw/endraw' answer with the most votes below, also check out "[How to escape liquid template tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3426182/102401)" that offers a commenting out type solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape liquid template tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can also use [raw](http://rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/Liquid/Raw):

```
{% raw %}

...lots of liquid code goes here and it doesn't get interpreted...

{% endraw %}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The following worked perfectly for me in a script template: `moneyFormat: {% raw %}'${{amount_no_decimals}}'{% endraw %}`

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 9):

What about using the numeric HTML entities `&#123;` and `&#125;` for `{` and `}` respectively - presumably this is to be output as HTML?

**EDIT:** Forgive me, I'm not too familiar with *liquid* (so this might be very wrong), but can you assign your `{{ example }}` special value to a variable and output that? May be something like:

```
{% assign special = '{{ example }}' %}
{{ special }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the output is ultimately going to be within a <script> tag, so using an entity won't work.

Comment: @Fortes I've updated my answer: can you assign your string with braces to a variable and output that instead?

Comment: Uh, is this the only way to display Liquid syntax in Liquid itself? I'm trying to display a whole template on a page that is generated with Liquid and it's messed up badly right now. Is there nothing like {{noparsefromhere}}...{{noparsetohere}}?

Comment: @cringe I would agree - there _should_ be a way. But I'm no expert with Liquid I'm afraid! Can you for instance load your entire _sub template_ (that you want to display as-is) into a template variable (without it being parsed) and display your variable in the main template? Or does that still get parsed?

Comment: @w3d Hm, that sounds like a way to do it... I don't know yet if I can load a whole template. But I think it's easier for me to just provide the actual template in source format and link to it directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only thing that worked from me. Lifted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5866429/9539):

```
{{ "{{ this " }}}}
```

I needed this because I wanted to reference the `site` global variable from inside a mustache template.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have both curly brackets AND angle brackets when formatting a fenced code block, so I ended up with the following pattern:

```
{% capture code %}{% raw %}line 1
line 2
line 3
{% endraw %}{% endcapture %}

<pre><code>{{ code | replace: "<", "&lt;" | replace: ">", "&gt;" }}</code></pre>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can escape the HTML, for example in a `{{var}}` you can use `\{\{var\}\}`, so that way luquid don't process it.

Comment: \{\{ does not work in Liquid. It will output both the slashes and the braces.