# How to escape liquid template tags?

Tags: templates, liquid

This sounds very easy, however I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs. How can I write `{% this %}` in a [liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) template, without it being processed by the engine?

Comment: You can always [comment out.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27007323/1934286)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

For future searchers, there *is* a way to escape without plugins, use the code below:

```
{{ "{% this " }}%}
```

and for tags, to escape `{{ this }}` use:

```
{{ "{{ this " }}}}
```

---

There is also a jekyll plugin for this which makes it a whole lot easier: https://gist.github.com/1020852

> Raw tag for jekyll. Keeps liquid from parsing text betweeen {% raw %}
>   and {% endraw %}

[Reference](http://tesoriere.com/2010/08/25/liquid-code-in-a-liquid-template-with-jekyll/)

Comment: Great, thanks for the reference. For some reason I wasn't able tno find this in the liquid docs.

Comment: You no longer need a plugin to use `{% raw %}`, for me it works out of the box and now it's in [the docs](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#wiki-raw)

Comment: is it possible to escape code with ``` instead of {% in jekyll?

Comment: The first couple suggestions didn't work for me, but using `raw` did: `{% raw %}{{ this }}{% endraw %}`.

Comment: it worked, thanks ... see a real example here http://g14n.info/2014/08/moving-from-blogger-to-github-pages/#comments

Answer (score 137):

it is possible to disable liquid processing engine using the `raw` tag:

```
{% raw  %}
{% this %}
{% endraw %}
```

will display

```
{% this %}
```

Comment: I believe this used to be a [plug-in](https://gist.github.com/1020852). Did it get into the core engine in the meantime?

Comment: It looks like the `raw` tag has been added a year ago in the core engine. See https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/commits/master/lib/liquid/tags/raw.rb

Comment: However, this escape is not supported by Github.

Comment: @LeiMing Looks like it is now (probably since [May 2013](https://github.com/blog/1502-jekyll-turns-1-0))

Comment: Confirmed, it works on GitHub Pages. The `raw` tag was [introduced in Liquid 2.3.0](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/425) and GitHub Pages is currently using [version 2.5.5](http://pages.github.com/versions).

Comment: One potential issue, if I want to print `{% endraw %}`, `{% raw %}{% endraw %}{% raw %}` won't render.

Answer (score 15):

You can escape liquid tags in Jekyll posts using  {% raw %} {% endraw %} i.e

```
{% raw %}
  {% for post in site.posts %}
     {{ post.content }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endraw %}
```

will produce

```
  {% for post in site.posts %}
     {{ post.content }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 14):

BTW:

If you want to display `{{ "{% this " }}%}`in Jekyll, you can code like this:

```
{{ "{{ " }}"{{ "{% this" }} " }}{{ "}}%}
```

To escape `{{ "{{ this " }}}}`use:

```
{{ "{{ " }}"{{ "{{ this" }} " }}{{ "}}}}
```

Comment: Ha, ha hahahah ah aaaaahhh.

Comment: wtf is going on here, I literally have no idea

Answer (score 10):

There is another option: to use HTML special characters codes for replacing the curly braces with its matching codes:

> - replace each **{** with **&#123;**
> - replace each **}** with **&#125;**

For more details about this solution see:
http://www.tikalk.com/devops/curly_brances_workaround/

Answer (score 4):

I found a omnipotent way to display any text with curly braces. You can assign plain text to a variable, and display it.

```
{% assign var = "{{ sth }}" %}
{{ var }}
```

Comment: Thank you! Useful to escape double or single quotes

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102498/escaping-double-curly-braces-inside-a-markdown-code-block-in-jekyll#57120434) also, plain `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` are only the second best solution since those are shown if you look up the Markdown on normal github.com.

The best way is to put `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` in HTML comments:

```
<!-- {% raw %} -->
something with curlky brackets like { this } and { that }
<!-- {% endraw %} -->
```

Due to the HTML comments it is seen by Github as a comment. In Github pages the raw tags will prevent the parsing of the curly brackets in between the tags.

Comment: I like this method as, for some reason, it doesn't mess with my excerpts.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `{% raw %}` something `{% endraw %}` ,

and `{{ "{% this " }}%}`. But they both don't work.

finally, my working answer is 
`{{ "{%" xxx }}  something }}`.

My code:

```html
{{ "{%" }} extends 'xadmin/base_site.html' %}
{{ "{%" }} block nav_form %}
    <h3>{{ "{{" }} title }}</h3>
    {{ "{%" }} for i in context1 %}
        <p>{{ "{{" }} i }}</p>
    {{ "{%" }} endfor %}
{{ "{%" }} endblock %}
```

The result:

```html
{% extends 'xadmin/base_site.html' %}
{% block nav_form %}
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    {% for i in context1 %}
        <p>{{ i }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allows output of Liquid code on a page without being parsed.

```
{% raw %}{{ 5 | plus: 6 }}{% endraw %} equals 11.

{{ 5 | plus: 6 }} equals 11.
```

For more details about this solution see: https://www.shoplazza.dev/docs/theme-tags