# Jekyll does not highlight django templates tag

Tags: django, templates, tags, highlight, jekyll

I'm working on jekyll (the static blogging engine) and a stubleupon some problems with the highlight template tag.

It's working for most of the cases but with django templates tag (with {{ or {% syntax ) it does not work, it just remove the line where are the templates tag.

For example, try this code in a jekyll post.

```
{% highlight html+django linenos %}
<form action="#" method="post">
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.name.errors %}
            <li>{{ error.0 }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ form.name.data }}" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% endhighlight %}
```

An answer will be to use HTML Entities of {, } and % but it's not very easy :)

Does anyone has an idea to fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot

Clément

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape liquid template tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way, but it is equally infuriating: [it involves lots of quotes](https://github.com/scottkf/tesoriere.com/blob/master/_posts/2010-08-25-liquid-code-in-a-liquid-template-with-jekyll.markdown#L9-17).

Appart from that, you are out of luck; Jekyll can't "escape" liquid.

Comment: This is ridiculous, you just have to wrap your code between {% raw %} {% endraw %}.

Comment: @JérômeMahuet you are not being fair, when I answered this question the `raw` tag did not exist. But you are welcome to answer yourself.

Comment: didn’t know that bro, sorry for being rude :)