# How to escape {{ in markdown on Octopress?

Tags: markdown, octopress

I'm using Octopress to blog, and I want to post the following code snippet (it's Mustache JS syntax):

````
```
<ul id="beers-list">
    {{#beers}}
        <li>{{name}} - {{color}} - {{alcohol}}%</li>
    {{/beers}}
</ul>
```
````

Unfortunately, when rendered, all `{{...}}` disappear, and I see the following on my website:

```
<ul id="beers-list">

        <li> -  - %</li>

</ul>
```

I was not able to escape the `{{` (even with `\{{`, `{\{` or something like that. Is there a way to escape these characters?

Thanks.

*I'm not sure if SO is the better site for this question*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to another quite similar question (and answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13582517/26457), I've found the solution. I have to wrap my code block with `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`:

````
{% raw %}
```
<ul id="beers-list">
    {{#beers}}
        <li>{{name}} - {{color}} - {{alcohol}}%</li>
    {{/beers}}
</ul>
```
{% endraw %}
````