# Jekyll print {{ in markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, ansible, octopress

I want to print {{ in markdown.

This is a sample ansible script that I want to display in my blog.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: True
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Add user
      user:
          name="{{ user }}"
          shell=/bin/bash
          state=present
          groups=staff
          append=yes
          createhome=yes
```

But when I render in browser, it shows

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: True
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Add user
      user:
          name=""
          shell=/bin/bash
          state=present
          groups=staff
          append=yes
          createhome=yes
```

If you see that, the name is not printing with {{ user }} but just "". Is there a way to print {{ }} ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape {{ in markdown on Octopress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786144/how-to-escape-in-markdown-on-octopress) or [Escaping double curly braces inside a markdown code block in Jekyll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102498/escaping-double-curly-braces-inside-a-markdown-code-block-in-jekyll)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a code block, you mean? Yes, it does.

```
"{% raw %} {{ user}} {% endraw %}"
```

Should do the job.

Hope to have helped! :)

Comment: While that works, there is another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags