# How to prevent the convert for the "^" to superscript?

Tags: markdown, octopress

I am writing a blog about block in Objective-C, by markdown and octopress. I wrote a lot of "^" character, which means the starting of block. But the markdown rendered it as a superscript automatically. I don't want this converting and would like to keep the "^" just as what it is. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Did you format it as code with backticks and/or indentation? If it needs to appear in plain text, you should be able to escape it with a backslash, as in ``\^``.

Comment: @Dan D. I have to write it as the plain text. There is not problem in the code snippets, but when I use "^" in plain text, it becomes <sup></sup>

Comment: @minitech I am using backticks. I have tried `\^` but with no luck. The output is something like this: `\<sup>some text</sup> `

Comment: I don’t know if that’s some kind of weird Octopress-flavoured-Markdown feature, but not being able to escape it sounds like a bug — try taking it up with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags/13582517#13582517). Thanks to @minitech, I should search "escape octopress markdown" for my question. Just use the `{% raw %}` tag so that it will be treated as the raw text. For the superscript, I changed `"^"` to `"{% raw %}^{% endraw %}"` and it worked well.