# Show raw tags in post generated by jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to show the raw tags in my post, like this:

```
{% raw %}
{% endraw %}
```

I put them in the raw tags (in org-mode):

```
#begin_example
{% raw %}
    {% raw %}
{% endraw%}
{% raw %}
    {% endraw}
{% endraw %}
#end_example
```

but it does not work and jekyll give me a error when I run

```
jekyll build
```

the error message is here:

```
Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'endraw' in _posts/2013-10-14-liquid-in-post.html
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: OK, I found the solution from this item.

just write the raw/endraw tag in this way:

{{ "{% raw " }}%}
{{ "{% endraw " }}%}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5866429/742173

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTML entities `&#123;` and `&#125;` for `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ raw }}` cannot be parsed inside `{{ raw }}` and `{{ endraw }}`

This snippet can do the job.

```
{% assign openTag = '{%' %}
{{ openTag }} raw %}
{{ openTag }} endraw %}
```