# How to use {{ }} brackets with html code on Github Flavored Markdown?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

I have next github markdown, where {{ product }} is an AngularJS template helper:

````
```html
<div ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="product in products">
            {{ product }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```
````

Unfortunately, output result does not contain brackets:

Is there a way i could solve this issue?

**Edit:**

This is my output html:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can't reproduce: https://monosnap.com/file/9GVsDIpjYE2VcF09gTvtjGdq95S0vk.png

Comment: I use Jekyll with github pages, possibly this cause

Comment: Yeah, jekyll uses liquid and liquid uses `{{ }}` for its variable expansion. So you need a way to suppress this liquid stuff for a block of text. Or escape the braces somehow.

Comment: Looks like this is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102537/2524304 (using {% raw %} content {% endraw %})

Comment: Looks like it, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw temporarily disables tag processing. This is useful for generating content (eg, Mustache, Handlebars) which uses conflicting syntax.

```
{% raw %}
  In Handlebars, {{ this }} will be HTML-escaped, but {{{ that }}} will not.
{% endraw %}
```

https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers#raw