# escape curly braces in github pages

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, liquid

I am using GitHub Pages for my project page.

The project is a simple programming language and I need to write examples code snippets in the documentation. My language needs to use `{%` and  `%}` literals quite often. In a `.md` file I wrote the following text:

```
Syntax: `{%=EXPRESSION%}`
```

I see that GitHub tried to interpret this text as a Liquid template expression and It could not build the page. Furthermore, I got an email about the page build failure.

```
The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

The tag `{%=EXPRESSION%}` on line 4 in `Functions.md` was 
not properly closed with `%}`. For more information, see 
https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-tag-not-properly-terminated/.
```

I do not want my markdown files to be parsed as Liquid templates. I just want these code examples presented as written without being evaluated.

1. How can I escape the `{%` literals?

   - I tried writing `&#123;` but it did not translate to open curly bracket character.
   - I also tried writing `{<i>% ... %</i>}` everywhere but then the `<i>` html tags did get escaped and the html code became visible in the output.
2. Is there a way to disable Liquid in a GitHub project page?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape liquid template tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags)

Comment: Another possible duplicate which is probably a better match: [Escaping double curly braces inside a markdown code block in Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24102498/866026).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping double curly braces inside a markdown code block in Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102498/escaping-double-curly-braces-inside-a-markdown-code-block-in-jekyll)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `{% raw %}` `{% endraw %}` tags

everything between this tags will Escape Liquid Template

example:

```
{% raw %}

{{8*8}}

{% endraw %}
```

and if you don't want this `{% raw %}` tags to appear in your github markdown you can comment them out it still works.

example:

```
<!--  {% raw %} --> 

{8*8}}

<!-- {% endraw %} -->
```