# How to escape GitHub Actions variables within code blocks when using README.md to create GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I use the GitHub pages feature whereby it [creates a GitHub Pages site by using the README.md file in your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-your-site). This works well, except for one problem. In my README.md file, I have code blocks illustrating the use of GitHub Actions workflows, and inside the code blocks, references to GitHub Actions variables of the form `${{github.foo.bar}}`. This is rendered fine on the repository page in GitHub, but in the corresponding GitHub Pages site, the variables disappear! Here is an actual example from [one of my repos](https://github.com/caltechlibrary/baler). First the relevant portion of the README.md as appears in the GitHub repository view:

[image]

Now the corresponding portion of the GitHub Pages result:

[image]

**How can I prevent this from happening?**

I thought about quoting the `$` characters using `\`, but the backslashes appear in the README.md view, and thus may lead people to copy incorrect GitHub Actions code.

Comment: I wonder if this is something that is fixable via GitHub Pages' Jekyll configuration options: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll#configuring-jekyll-in-your-github-pages-site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping double curly braces inside a markdown code block in Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102498/escaping-double-curly-braces-inside-a-markdown-code-block-in-jekyll)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120434/3266847).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tested it, and it works! I used the approach suggested in [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102498/escaping-double-curly-braces-inside-a-markdown-code-block-in-jekyll/57120434#comment131051181_57120434), to put raw/endraw around the entire README.md file, and it works perfectly, with no negative consequence that I can see. Thanks for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Jekyll (the static site generator used by GitHub Pages) is seeing `{{stuff}}` and trying to expand it (because it uses `{{…}}` to inline variables). You can prevent Jekyll from doing this by using `{% raw %}{{…}}{% endraw %}` in your Markdown file, but then that text will show up as-is on the GitHub repository home page (which shows `README.md` as HTMLified Markdown *without* running it through Jekyll expression expansion). I don't know of a way to have just `{{…}}` show up in the GitHub repo home page *and* in the rendered GitHub Pages site :-(

Comment: I found this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120434/27310 which suggests wrapping the `{% raw %}` tags in HTML comments to hide them from Markdown generators, e.g.  `<!-- {% raw %} -->`, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: That `<!-- {% raw %} -->` / `<-- {% endraw %} -->` seems to be the best way, and I'd say this is a duplicate question then.