# How do you comment out in Liquid?

Tags: syntax, liquid, comments

What is the correct way to comment out in the Liquid templating language?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

In [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) you comment out using the `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}` tags:

```
{% comment %} This is a comment in Liquid {% endcomment %}
```

It doesn't matter if the comment is inline or a block comment.

```
{% comment %}
    This is a block comment in Liquid
{% endcomment %}
```

Comment: This is a surprisingly verbose and non-ergonomic syntax. I was expecting to be able to do something like line `/* Fnord */` inside a `{% %}` run, e.g. `{% elseif /* do the other thing:*/ %}`. That's a shame.

Comment: this does not work properly for commenting out say an `{% if .. %} ` so its not only verbose, its a bit trashy too

Comment: correct answer is the one with only a few upvotes below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867876/533426

Answer (score 21):

If, like me, you are looking for a solution that **actually** comments out **"anything"/everything** between the comment tags (as described in the [documentation](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/comment/)), you can use the `{% raw %}` tag (in conjuction with the `{% comment %}` tag if you don't want anything rendered in the browser).

**Example:**

```
{% comment %}
    {% raw %}
        Here is some text that I don't want displayed and
        {% some_liquid_stuff_that_I_don't_want_parsed %}
    {% endraw %}
{% endcomment %}
```

will render nothing at all.

In contrast,

```
{% raw %}
    Here is some text that I want displayed but
    {% some_liquid_stuff_that_I_don't_want_parsed %}
{% endraw %}
```

will render

> Here is some text that I want displayed but
>
> {% some_liquid_stuff_that_I_don't_want_parsed %}

while

```
{% comment %}
    Here is some text that I don't want displayed but
    {% some_liquid_stuff_that_will_be_parsed %}
{% endcomment %}
```

may result in a syntax error or Liquid exception, depending on the validity of the Liquid inside the comment tags.

An example of where this becomes an issue is where some work-in-progress code has been commented out:

```
{% comment %}
    {% if some test %}
         some stuff to render
    {% elsif... %}
         unfinished code...
{% endcomment %}
```

(In this case you may end up with an unfinished if statement error.)

Additional information on [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/313).

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you. This is also unbelievably verbose.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Liquid 5.4.0 you will be able to use a short inline comment that does not require a closing tag! The syntax is:

```
{% # This is a new inline comment! %}
```

As with other tags you can add hyphens to remove whitespace around it:

```
{%- # This is a new inline comment without whitespace! -%}
```

And even use multiple lines:

```
{%- 
################################
#  This is a really big block  #
################################ 
-%}
```

More info is available in [the merged PR](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/1498).

Comment: Oh, that sounds cool. Too bad Jekyll 4 is stuck with Liquid 4!

Answer (score 7):

Liquid allows you to leave un-rendered code inside a Liquid template by using the `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}` tags.

**Input:**

```
Anything you put between {% comment %} and {% endcomment %} tags
is turned into a comment.
```

**Output:**

```
Anything you put between  tags
is turned into a comment.
```

Reference documentation: [Comment tag in Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/comment/)

Comment: I really enjoyed the way you did this example so it made readable sense in the input and the output.

Answer (score 2):

In liquid, you use `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}` tags:

```
{% comment %} This would be commented out {% endcomment %}
```

You can also use it in block:

```
{% comment %}
    This would also be commented out
{% endcomment %}
```

If the `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}` tags would comment anything, including HTML elements and such:

```
 {% comment %}
    <div class="commented_out">
    <p>This whole div would be commented out</p>
    </div>
{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the liquid, using comment tag enclose the text to be commented inside the comment tag

```
{%comment%}
Text to be commented
{%endcomment%}
```