# How do I get the correct html line comment in VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, angular5

I am working on a sample Angular 5 project in Visual Studio Code. I need to comment a line of html out. I have tried both clicking on the edit menu  and the keyboard shortcut 
ctrl+/ and get the same result from both. What I get is:

```
{% comment %} <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">  {% endcomment %}
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
<!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName"> -->
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: what is the file type? looks like it is taking it as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007323/how-do-you-comment-out-in-liquid

Comment: Also am not able to repro this in vscode

Comment: The file type is html. To my knowledge I have never used Liquid or any other templating language.

Comment: That is strange.. it's not insiders build is it?

Comment: Found out the file type to language association was set to Django html. When I tried to change it to HTML there was no HTML listed in the languages. I uninstalled VSCode and reinstalled it. I was then able to make the correct association and it works as expected now. Thanks for the reply.