# Can't get double curly brackets to display

Tags: markdown, jekyll, morea-framework

I have some markdown in Morea which includes an example Jinja2 template. It looks like this:

```
{% highlight html linenos %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p> {{ greet }}, {{ place }} </p>
</body>
</html>
{% endhighlight %}
```

I would like to be able to display the double curly braces, but they get swallowed up, displaying nothing but the paragraph tags and the comma, like this:

```
<p>  ,   </p>
```

I followed some advice to use the {% raw %} and {% endraw %} tags around that line, but nothing changes. Seems like a bug. Anyone have any tricks?

Comment: I've found a crazy way to do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags#answer-5866429). Perhaps can be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eek.  There appears to be some double-escaping going on with the Morea plugin.  The only solution I can come up with quickly is to embed a gist with the code containing the offending liquid tag. Here is a sample page illustrating this approach:

[image]

I will continue to look into this. Note that to embed gists you'll need to install the jekyll-gist gem and then add the following to your config.yml:

`gems:
  - jekyll-gist`

Comment: Thanks for confirming the problem and for the details on how to include gists.

Answer (score 1):

Surround code containing curly braces with the `raw` tag :

```
{% highlight html linenos %}
{% raw %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p> {{ greet }}, {{ place }} </p>
</body>
</html>
{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Could you post a screen image showing this approach working with a [Morea Framework](http://morea-framework.github.io) site? It didn't work for the original poster or for me.

Comment: @PhilipJohnson I'll be plesed to help you. Can you provide a repository url ? I'll try to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks. A sample repo is [basic-template2 repo](https://github.com/morea-framework/basic-template2) with corresponding [basic-template2 site](http://morea-framework.github.io/basic-template2/). After cloning, you might want to try fiddling with the [MathJax samples](https://github.com/morea-framework/basic-template2/blob/master/src/morea/foo/reading-1.md) page source.

Comment: Sorry but `{%raw%}\\[ \frac{1}{n^{2}} \\]{%endraw}` works perfectly here.

Comment: Exactly. So why doesn't `{%raw%} {{ greet }} {%endraw}` work perfectly as well?

Comment: Can you, please, write a dedicated question that describes your input, your expected output, and the problem you're facing. Comments are not supposed to be a resolution way on SO.

Comment: Hi David! My question above has an example of my input and describes my expected output. {%raw%} isn't working for me when using the morea-framework. Is there anything I should add or change to make it more useful?

Comment: you ended my two-day misery!! +1

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

````
```
{% raw %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p> {{ greet }}, {{ place }} </p>
</body>
</html>
{% endraw %}
```
````

Comment: Please explain your problem and provide you js code as well.