# How to get the base asset url in a Shopify liquid theme?

Tags: shopify, mustache, liquid, vue.js

is there a way to get the base asset url in a Shopify liquid theme?

I'm translating a page to Shopify. This page uses Vuejs data binding like so:

```
<img src="/path/to/assets/folder/{{ color }}1.jpg">
```

I can't pass the curly braces to the filter because it will URL encode it. If I had access to the asset url it would be simple.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can [escape liquid templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags), so your tag would be like this

```
<img src="/path/to/assets/folder/{{ "{{ color " }}}}1.jpg">
```

not nice if you ask me. But there is another option, use vue bind instead of text interpolation, so there is no curly braces, when you use the `v-bind` directive, then you write pure javascript for that directive, so you quote your `src` attribute, or add it to a variable of your component.

usign the text

```
<img :src=" '/path/to/assets/folder/' + color + '1.jpg' ">
```

usign a variable

```
<!-- template -->
<img :src="img_path">

// js, data or props attribute
img_path: '/path/to/assets/folder/' + color + '1.jpg'
```

note: I used the shorthand version of `v-bind:src => :src`

Comment: I would use computed properties for the img src. 

    img_path () {
      return '/path/to/assets/folder/' + color + '1.jpg'
    }