# Include Jekyll/Liquid code without rendering it

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to `{% include file.html %}` without the tags inside it getting rendered?

- I've tried `{% include file.html | escape_once %}` which gives an
  error
- [running it through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags) `{% raw %} {% include file.html %} {% endraw %}`
  which gives `{% include file.html %}` (not surprisingly).

I'm looking for something along the lines of `{% include file.html | no_render %}`

The reason I can't put the raw tags inside `file.html` is that I'm trying to reuse it as a template (it's a bit of a hack).

This would also be good for pages that are trying to self describe. I.e. `This useful thing works like this: {% include useful_snippet.html | no_render %}`

Comment: Did you ever get this working with a generator plugin or hooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**useful_snippet.html**

```
{% raw %}
  {% comment %}Alot of liquid code{% endcomment %}
  {% assign toto = "Welcome to the hack !" %}
  {% assign string = "a,b,c,d" %}
  {% assign array = string | split:"," %}
  {% for item in array %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endraw %}
```

#### base display

```
<pre><code>{% include useful_snippet.html %}</code></pre>
```

#### display with jekyll highlight tag

```
{% highlight liquid %}{% include useful_snippet.html %}{% endhighlight %}
```

**Edit**: In Jekyll only process, Liquid is rendered once. So, no way to get one template doing both rendering Liquid and rendering raw Liquid code.

If you want to go that way, you'll have to use [generator plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) or [hooks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks).

Comment: Doesn't this make the template essentially plain text? `highlight` displays it as pretty Liquid, but there's no way to reverse the process and include that liquid into another file and have it rendered. I wanted the code to do double duty to cut down on repeating myself.

Comment: @Ben I'm trying to do the exact same thing. What did you end up using? Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the **useful_snippet.html** solution with some variations and discussed this and a few other options for small code blocks at [Jekyll: Display Liquid code in a post](https://davidjones.sportronics.com.au/web/Jekyll-Display_Liquid_code_in_a_post-web.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had no luck wrapping thing in `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`. 
My mix of js/html got slightly modified by the parser, breaking things.

In order to include js/html as raw, I use [kramdown's nomarkdown extension](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#extensions), like this:

```
{::nomarkdown}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.pouet.net/pouet-player.js" async defer></script>
<div class="pouet-player" data-version="v1" data-size="medium"><a href='https://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=30244'>fr-041: debris. by Farbrausch</a></div>
{:/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a custom tag:

Put `raw_include_relative.rb` in `_plugins/` directory at your Jekyll root:

```rb
# _plugins/raw_include_relative.rb
module Jekyll
  module Tags
    class RawIncludeRelativeTag < IncludeRelativeTag
      # Overriding is explicitly allowed, to modify file content by subclassing:
      # https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/f5826eed3cde692f84e35140209d5a59ec3eb295/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb#L178
      def read_file(file, context)
        # Hack: instead of including the file directly without liquid escaping,
        # simply wrap the entire file in a `raw` liquid tag, suppressing liquid
        # processing.
        "{% raw %}" + super + "{% endraw %}"
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag("raw_include_relative", Jekyll::Tags::RawIncludeRelativeTag)
```

Then you can use `{% raw_include_relative somefile.txt %}` just as you would use `include_relative`.

[In-practice example](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz.gitlab.io/-/blob/master/_plugins/raw_include_relative.rb).