# How to use {{ }} with Markdown

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I would like to write `{{ ... }}` inside a code block using Markdown.

For example:

```
{{ var }}
```

I don't know why it disappears. However I can write it outside a block of code: \ {\ { var \ } \ }.

Comment: Two things to try: (1) make sure you don't have a space between two of the backticks on the code-block starter line; (2) try using an indented code block instead of a fenced code block.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I just copy-and-pasted your question to a new GitHub Gist. The braces display correctly. https://gist.github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/43ba8e724b2f733c5e1d20e557161b20

Comment: @KeithThompson Try the [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29d2e9cd-7279-4e86-ae2d-5f4a90181342/view-source)

Comment: OP is probably using Jekyll to build his github pages and var is being resolved to a variable with an empty value

Comment: Yes, I'm using Jekyll. I'll see your answer Macel.

Comment: @cricket_007: I just copy-and-pasted the original version of the question into the same Gist, file `README_0.md`. I see a stray backtick, but the braces still display correctly, at least in my browser (Chrome on Ubuntu). (Apparently Jekyll is an issue; I don't know anything about that.)

Comment: @cricket_007 is different using Jekyll. Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags

Answer (score 2):

#### Github flavored markdown supports that

You should be able to do exactly that. I think you must be using a bugged markdown implementation (or one with a 'templating mechanism' where {{ xxx }} is treated like variable interpolation), in normal markdown the following code block should work:

```
{{ var }}
```

As you can see, the StackOverflow markdown processor is doing the right thing, it is putting `{{ var }}` verbatim in the code block.

#### But Jekyll is another story

If you are using Jekyll to create your github pages, be aware that {{ }} is used for variable interpolation. Jekyll uses Liquid for this. Documentation:

- https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers
- https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/

Your answer is probably here (there are multiple options): [How to escape liquid template tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426182/how-to-escape-liquid-template-tags)

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't use the Github-flavored Markdown, though

Comment: Look at https://github.com/marcel-valdez/x-window-shortcuts/issues/1 <--- github flavored markdown with OP's example in it

Comment: I was mostly referring to both your and OP's posts here containing triple-backticks for code blocks,

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this.

```
{% highlight liquid %}
  {% raw %}
    {{ Your code here }}
  {% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

This will output the following code:

```
<code class="language-liquid" data-lang="liquid">  
  <span class="p">{{</span>
  <span class="w"> </span>
  <span class="nv">Your code here</span>
  <span class="w"> </span>
  <span class="p">}}</span>
</code>
```