# Send ID of changed row in table (html to JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 7 row and i need to use my function only for row which was edited. How can i send id? or maybe there are more easy way? I tried to send number of row id `onChange="setprice(this.value,18,5)"` last one is ID of row, but on split int+ string I can not detetct it as ID . For example:
`var idofrow = ('setvalue'+row); $("#idofrow").html("");`. `#idofrow` does not work

```js
function setprice(val, ay, row) {
  var rowid_ilk = event.target.getAttribute('id');
  $("#rowid_ilk").html("");
  var total = Math.round((((({{ price_without_symbol }  } - val) / ay) * ({{      kredittable.kredit_faiz / 100 }})) + (({{ price_without_symbol }} - val) / ay)));
  var rowset = 'setvalue' + row;
  alert(rowset);
  rowset.innerHTML += total;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="tablebrd">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">{{ text_kredit_mesac }}</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 28%">{{ text_min_vznos }}</th>
      <th scope="col">{{ text_mes_plata }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3 {{ text_kredit_mesaca }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ilkoden" id="ilkoden1" value="{{ kredittable.kredit_min_ilkin  }}" onChange="setprice(this.value,3,1)" /></td>
      <td>
        <div id="setvalue1"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6 {{ text_kredit_mesaca }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ilkoden" id="ilkoden2" value="{{ kredittable.kredit_min_ilkin  }}" onChange="setprice(this.value,6,2)" /></td>
      <td>
        <div id="setvalue2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>9 {{ text_kredit_mesaca }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ilkoden" id="ilkoden3" value="{{ kredittable.kredit_min_ilkin  }}" onChange="setprice(this.value,9,3)" /></td>
      <td>
        <div id="setvalue3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>12 {{ text_kredit_mesaca }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ilkoden" id="ilkoden4" value="{{ kredittable.kredit_min_ilkin  }}" onChange="setprice(this.value,12,4)" /></td>
      <td>
        <div id="setvalue4"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>18 {{ text_kredit_mesaca }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ilkoden" id="ilkoden5" value="{{ kredittable.kredit_min_ilkin  }}" onChange="setprice(this.value,18,5)" /></td>
      <td>
        <div id="setvalue5"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>24 {{ text_kredit_mesaca }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ilkoden" id="ilkoden6" value="{{ kredittable.kredit_min_ilkin  }}" onChange="setprice(this.value,24,6)" /></td>
      <td>
        <div id="setvalue6"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>36 {{ text_kredit_mesaca }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="ilkoden" id="ilkoden7" value="{{ kredittable.kredit_min_ilkin  }}" onChange="setprice(this.value,36,7)" /></td>
      <td>
        <div id="setvalue7"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `id` of your changed element by accessing the `target` property of the event: [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

> [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is a reference to the object that dispatched the event

Then access its `id` name with [`.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute). And remove the first seven letters of the id name to get the element's number with the method [`.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

```
event.target.getAttribute('id').substr(7)
```

---

Here's a quick demo:

```js
const fn = function() {
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute('id').substr(7))
}
```

```html
<div id="ilkoden11" onclick="fn()">This is item 11</div>
```

---

If you want to select the id of an element on the same level, you will need to do some navigating inside the HTML tree, the following selector will do that:

```
const div = event.target.closest('tr').querySelector('div').id;
                              ↑                  ↑
                        parent <tr>      find <div> child
```

Here is an example:

```js
const setprice = function() {
  const target = event.target.id;
  const value = event.target.value;
  const div = event.target.closest('tr').querySelector('div').id;
  console.log(target, value, div)
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input id="ilkoden2" onkeyup="setprice()" /></td>
  <td>
    <div id="setvalue2"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dear Ivan,thank you for reply. In this case i can send 1 ID only, but what to do with second ID of div? I am getting value of first input and use it in formula to get result. This result by innerHTML i am adding to DIV with another ID.
P.S. I can not join ID(int) with string and write it as ID `#string_plus_int`

Comment: Are you using some kind of library?

Comment: Why do you have those curly brackets `{` and `}`?

Comment: @Ivan - Those look like either [Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330979/outputting-literal-curly-braces-in-liquid-templates) or [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js) braces.... those are the "variable" braces, so Angular / Liquid (or whatever language) will render the contents of those variables.  I'm hoping it's _not_ angular, since OP is using a lot of jQuery, which shouldn't be necessary / used in an Angular app :)

Comment: It is MVC php on opencart 3.0.2.0 version. `{{ variable }}` it is same thing as `<?php echo $variable; ?>` which i should pass and define in controller, model, language and finally in view

Comment: Thank you @cale_b, Orik00 I have edited my answer to allow the selection of the `div`'s id.

Comment: @cale_b yes,exactly as "Liquid. It came with 3-rd version, old version is more comfortable i think, loops same as PHP.

Comment: @Orik00 did you try my second snippet?

Comment: @Ivan just tested and it is perfect, thank you very much, you are awesome!)

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)

Comment: @Ivan I still have problem. If i write`div.innerHTML += total;` it is not working, but if i write `setvalue2.innertHTML += total;` it works. Why? i thought your code is solved this problem, but still same

Comment: `total` is an Integer, what do you want to do with it? Do you want to sum values, assign `total` or add `total` content to the page?

Comment: @Ivan I have 7 rows with 3 columns(**1-st column we need for formula**). `target ` - is id of editable input(int). `value` - is value of `target`(**2-nd column**). `div`- is id of DIV where we should print `total`(**3-rd column**). `div.innerHTML += total;` div is not working here, does not show id of div to print it

Comment: @Ivan my stupid mistake... i should use ` document.getElementById(div).innerHTML += total;` to make it see at as ID. Thank you very much for help!)

Comment: Indeed, or you can set the element in the variable instead: `const div = event.target.closest('tr').querySelector('div')`. So then you can access its id with `div.id` and add some HTML with `div.innerHTML +=`. Though you should take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code) which explains why adding HTML with `.innerHTML +=` is not very good. Don't worry, for now, since you're starting off in JavaScript you don't have to worry about that ;)

Comment: @Ivan Thank you for help and for documentations, i will read and will try to fix it :)